# Как связать фронт и бек

Tags: reactjs, laravel

Скачал из гитхаба фронтскую и бекенд части.
Фронт на react,бекенд на laravel.
Запустил бекенд localhost:8000 и запустил фронт localhost:3000,всё правильно работает.Но на фронте много чего не выводится.В беке уже настроена связка с фронтом.Но некорректно отображается.Миграцию тоже сделал и сид прописал php artisan db:seed,но опять же ноль изменений.

Есть ли какая та документация про это?Я знаю,что я вопрос не полностью написал.

Comment: Не известно, что конкретно вы качали с гитлаба) Под понятием "связать" вы имеете ввиду https://inertiajs.com/ ?)

Comment: Клиент должен с 3000 порта ходить на 8000 порт за данными. Смотрите в консоли, что куда отправляется, какие ошибки и т.д.

Comment: Ошибка связана с jwt secret,secret is not set

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была связана с jwt аунтефикация

Решение : в консоли прописать php artisan jwt:secret